# Vuestic-ui VaCheckbox Component is missing template or render function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuestic

I am using it with Laravel 8 and VUEJS 3.

Everything works fine except " VaCheckbox " gives this message.

```
" Component is missing template or render function "
```

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using Vuestic
Solved when fix version on `package.json` to `1.3.4`

```
"vuestic-ui": "1.3.4",
```

Then run

```
npm i
```